# turn on click event after turning off

Tags: jquery

I want to turn the click events again after the click event is turned off.

In my example if `hide` text is clicked then it unbind the click event for this. And now again if `show` text is clicked then `hide` text click should be able to click.

```
$('.hide').on('click',function(){
    $('#main').animate({height: 0},400);
    $(this).off('click');

});
$('.show').on('click',function(){
    $('#main').animate({height: '200px'},400);
    $('.hide').on('click'); //I'm stuck (not able to click after unbind click)

});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1j1gpsf1/)

Comment: try to use [namespace](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rebind it.

```
function myEvent_On() {
  $('.hide').on('click',function(){
    $('#main').animate({height: 0},400);
    $(this).off('click');

  });
}

myEvent_On();
$('.show').on('click',function(){
    $('#main').animate({height: '200px'},400);
    myEvent_On();
});
```